# RTS Game Protocol

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been thinking about a multi player RTS game.  The part that I can't seem to get around is keeping unit movement synced.  If I move unit A to spot XY, I have to communicate that back to server that relays to the other client.

I'm curious what the communications would look like.  Would you just communicate to the server that I'm moving unit A to XY from JZ?  Maybe you need to communicate movement coord by coord instead?  What's the most efficient methodology to communicate movement of units from one client to the other?

Comment: Note: reposted at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/rts-game-protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're intending to use the Client-Server networking paradigm? In which case you cannot trust the clients to handle the actual positioning of units, you must delegate that task to the server. You then take the command list from each client per-tick, and compute the movement of each unit, once this has been completed, next tick you relay the position of each unit relevant to each client (either on a whole-map basis, or per-view basis), and start the process again.

If you're only interested in a Peer-to-Peer paradigm, the process is somewhat simpler, as you can either use a circle chain, in which case each client is receiving from one client only and sending to one client only, which can be visualized as a circle of clients each sending and receiving, or a (highly-inefficient) system whereby the client sends the position of his units to each other client, and receives the position of the other's units from every other client.

Personally, I believe the Client-Server paradigm will be the better option, as you remove the effects of cumulative latency, and the issue of a rogue client.

Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: I figured as much for the server handling the positioning.  I suppose that on each tick, I can send the location and status of an object to each client.  The location info is obvious.  Maybe the status tells the client that if the object is moving, and the client does the appropriate animation of the sprite.  Sound appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I would build a system were all visual features (I.e rendering informatio, animation etc.) is done client-side and critical data handling is server-side. The status should contain information such as health, animation info, anything that we shouldn't trust the client with basically.

Comment: @Darthg8r: Almost all RTS's use a peer-to-peer architecture - client-server is extremely atypical.  See [my answer to your gamedev.stackexchange.com question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/rts-game-protocol/15196#15196) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i'd think that you'd tell the server to move unit A to spot XY and it would tell all the clients the current location of the unit (if they can see that unit) as it moves at each time step. this basically puts the path finding and battle processing on the server.